# BackboneJS - pushState and Images

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm running a backbone project on my localhost. I have set `pushState: true` on my main router. On my index.html i have multiple views which contain images. Those views render a html-template in which the path to the image is defined:

```
<div>
   <img src="images/image1.jpg">
</div>
```

Now, when clicking a specific link I have defined in my menu view:

```
secondpage: function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var newRouter = new Backbone.Router();
   var route = '/secondpage';
   newRouter.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
},
```

After this, my URL gets changed into `localhost/secondpage`, so far so good, but now, my view on the second page, which also contains an image (lets say image2) is not getting displayed and I get the error `http://localhost/images/image2.jpg` not found...

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

the path to your image should be something like */images/image2.jpg*

```
<div>
   <img src="/images/image1.jpg">
</div>
```